# Google+ api doesn't return profile name with login request

Tags: google-api, google-plus

The google documentation [HERE](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes) clearly says that

> You should not request userinfo.profile or plus.me in combination with [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login] scope as they are implicitly included and would create a confusing permissions dialog for your user.

... yet if I don't use

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` along with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` the api will not return the user's email address or name.

If I'm not supposed to `userinfo` scope along with the `plus.login` scope how do I get the the user's name and email?

Answer (score 3):

You need `userinfo.email` to get the email address, but you should be able to request that *without* also requesting `userinfo.profile`. `plus.login` should give you access to the "GET /plus/v1/people/{userid}" call which should return the following fields/objects (at a minimum):

- name - an object containing the name broken down into fields
- displayName
- nickname

Comment: after you've authenticated, yes, you can make a separate request to /plus/v1/people/{userid}

Comment: Generally, it helps to call people.get in the sign-in callback function in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I also got into difficulty getting the profile and e-mail address. Finally I found that I can use these scopes to get everything:

'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'email', 'profile'

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Google is a little vague in its documentation. They say the scope 'plus.login' contains the displayName and email, however, after running several tests with different Google accounts (plain Gmail, Google+, Google Apps) this seems to be false.

If the user doesn't have a Google+ profile, 'plus.login' will NOT contain displayName. This also seems to happen to Google Apps accounts. So, to cover all possible Google Account status, the safe bet is to request for:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

They say the last 2 are deprecated, however, some accounts will not return all basic information if you don't use them. I don't know if this is related to the "age" of the Google account or just a bug on Google's end.

Answer (score 1):

Works on me this way

scope = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile email

between **userinfo.profile** and **email** has space in it

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks! Its fascinating that Google would have 1000 pages of documents, but fail to mention such key information.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved multi-scoping using following scope param.

> scope = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+profile