# Retrieve email and phone number via Google API

Tags: coldfusion, google-plus

I am working with Google API using Coldfusion, So making a call to the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userID}?key={MyGoogleKey}
```

I am able to get the details of the user. Whatever they have shared in their google plus account. One thing that is missing is their email address and phone numbers (if available).

I think, I need to make another call to the API to get the email and phone numbers, but I am struggling with how to do that. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
<cfset objGoogPlus = createObject("component","services.auth").init(apikey="#application.google_server_key#",parseResults=true)>
    <cfdump var="#objGoogPlus.people_get(userID='#data.id#')#">


<cffunction name="init" access="public" output="false" hint="I am the constructor method.">
        <cfargument name="apiKey"           required="true"     type="string"                   hint="I am the application's API key to access the services." />
        <cfargument name="parseResults"     required="false"    type="boolean"  default="false" hint="A boolean value to determine if the output data is parsed or returned as a string" />
            <cfset variables.instance.apikey        =   arguments.apiKey />
            <cfset variables.instance.parseResults  =   arguments.parseResults />
            <cfset variables.instance.endpoint      =   'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/' />
        <cfreturn this />
    </cffunction>

<cffunction name="getparseResults" access="package" output="false" hint="I return the parseresults boolean value.">
        <cfreturn variables.instance.parseResults />
    </cffunction>

<cffunction name="people_get" access="public" output="false" hint="I get a person's profile.">
        <cfargument name="userID"           required="true"     type="string"                                   hint="The ID of the person to get the profile for. The special value 'me' can be used to indicate the authenticated user." />
        <cfargument name="parseResults"     required="false"    type="boolean"  default="#getparseResults()#"   hint="A boolean value to determine if the output data is parsed or returned as a string" />
            <cfset var strRequest   =   variables.instance.endpoint & 'people/' & arguments.userID & '?key=' & variables.instance.apikey />
        <cfreturn getRequest(URLResource=strRequest, parseResults=arguments.parseResults) />
    </cffunction>

<cffunction name="getRequest" access="private" output="false" hint="I make the GET request to the API.">
        <cfargument name="URLResource"  required="true" type="string"   hint="I am the URL to which the request is made." />
        <cfargument name="parseResults" required="true" type="boolean"  hint="A boolean value to determine if the output data is parsed or returned as a string" />
            <cfset var cfhttp   =   '' />
                <cfhttp url="#arguments.URLResource#" method="get" />
        <cfreturn handleReturnFormat(data=cfhttp.FileContent, parseResults=arguments.parseResults) />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="handleReturnFormat" access="private" output="false" hint="I handle how the data is returned based upon the provided format">
        <cfargument name="data"         required="true" type="string"   hint="The data returned from the API." />
        <cfargument name="parseResults" required="true" type="boolean"  hint="A boolean value to determine if the output data is parsed or returned as a string" />
            <cfif arguments.parseResults>
                <cfreturn DeserializeJSON(arguments.data) />
            <cfelse>
                <cfreturn serializeJSON(DeserializeJSON(arguments.data)) />
            </cfif>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction access="public" name="getProfileEmail" returntype="any" returnformat="json">
      <cfargument name="accesstoken" default="" required="yes" type="any"> 
      <cfhttp url="googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"; method="get" resolveurl="yes" result="httpResult"> 
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="OAuth #arguments.accesstoken#"> 
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="GData-Version" value="3"> 
      </cfhttp> 
      <cfreturn DeserializeJSON(httpResult.filecontent.toString())> 
    </cffunction>
```

I do not what to say, but i used the following method and its seems to bring the email-address, not with new way but with old way:

```
<cfset googleLogin = objLogin.initiate_login(
                loginUrlBase = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                loginClientID = application.google_client_id,
                loginRedirectURI = application.google_redirecturl,
                loginScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
            )>
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/people) I don't see anywhere in the results that includes email or phone number

Comment: Yes, I see too that in documentation, it is not applicable, but i read it here on stackoverflow somewhere that we need to make an additional request to the api so it can fetch email address, i read it in php specific area

Comment: oh really?  Give us a link here to where it mentions how to do that in PHP; shouldn't be too hard to rewrite to CF

Comment: Some of what you're looking for is controlled by the scopes you provided to OAuth, so please indicate the scopes you're using. (And this has changed very recently, so even recent answers elsewhere may no longer apply - you can do this in one call now.)

Comment: this question sems addressing same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066222/google-api-doesnt-return-profile-name-with-login-request. But i amstill lost where to actually make a call to request for email, using the token or the apikey

Comment: I've added the getProfileEmail function you posted below to the question to be clear. You imply the userinfo scopes from it, but you STILL haven't posted the scopes you're using.

Answer (score 3):

I discuss Google+ and Sign In via this blog post (http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/2/20/Google-SignIn-and-ColdFusion), and yes, I know it is bad to just point to a blog post so none of my hard work there will be appreciated by SO (sigh). As Prisoner said, what you get is based on the scopes initially requested. Here are the docs on additional scopes: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes. Email is there, but not phone as far as I see. And to be honest, I don't see a place to enter my phone # at Google+ anyway.

Comment: But Ray, According to the Docs: **the user's Google account email address. You access the email address by calling people.get, which returns the emails array (or by calling people.getOpenIdConnect, which returns the email property in OIDC-compliant format).**. people.get does not return the emails array

Comment: Testing using my demo (I shared the code on the link above), I *do* get an email array back. Have you tried my code yet?

Comment: I repeat my comment - post what scopes you're using. The scopes are the key here.

Comment: I added function,tell me if thatis wrong:<cffunction access="public" name="getProfileEmail" returntype="any" returnformat="json">
     <cfargument name="accesstoken" default="" required="yes" type="any">
        <cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo" method="get" resolveurl="yes" result="httpResult"> 
         <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="OAuth #arguments.accesstoken#">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="GData-Version" value="3">
        </cfhttp>
        <cfreturn DeserializeJSON(httpResult.filecontent.toString())>    
    </cffunction>

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "getProfileEmail" function that you've added, it looks like you're using the userinfo scope and access point. Google [has announced that this method is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable) and will be removed in September 2014.

You should switch to using the [people.get method](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#email) and adding the [email](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email) scope to the G+ Sign-in button that Raymond has outlined on his blog.

**Update**

In your call to `objLogin.initiate_login` you should change the `loginScope` parameter to use **both** the *profile* and *email* scopes at a minimum (see https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes for a more complete list of scopes you may wish to use). So it might look something like:

```
<cfset googleLogin = objLogin.initiate_login(
         loginUrlBase = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
         loginClientID = application.google_client_id,
         loginRedirectURI = application.google_redirecturl,
         loginScope = "profile email"
       )>
```

You can then use the [people.get API call](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#email) to get the information you need. Looking at your `getRequest` function, however, this appears to call *people.get* using the API Key, which is insufficient to get email - all it can do is get public information. You need to call *people.get* in the same way you called *userinfo* in the `getProfileEmail` function. I don't know ColdFusion well enough, but you should be able to adapt this function to call the [people.get endpoint](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#email) instead.

Comment: Ray has completely changed the oAuth3 Login which was of google, He has focussed on Google+, So my Application is makings calls to the google api successfully, and i am also making a call to the google+ plus additoinal functions to fetch user details, all is going well, only issues lies with the email functionality

Comment: i tried same functionality in google api console and got email, but when i tried same using the cfhttp it showed empty strings, i can share code if needed

Comment: Tried this code in cflive.net, i got empty {}.. tried same code in the google console, got the email address <cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/113377691202864347297?fields=emails&key=AIzaSyA" method="get" resolveurl="yes" result="httpResult"><cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer k7wYQpqZM"><cfhttpparam type="header" name="GData-Version" value="3">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-JavaScript-User-Agent:" value="Google APIs Explorer"> 
  </cfhttp><cfoutput>#httpResult.filecontent#</cfoutput>  
      <cfdump var="#httpResult#">

Comment: (1) Please don't post code in comments. It is quite impossible to read. Edit the original post.  (2) I have asked three times now, and I don't see you answering it anywhere: What Scopes are you asking for? Show us the code for the Google+ Sign-In button you are using. The data-scope parameter there is utterly crucial to getting the data you need.

Comment: Updated answer with info about scopes and a problem i noticed with your function call.